# does the NEC allow conduit attached to my house to an outbuilding or does it have to be buried?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, nec

I have a shed im running electrical to, which is detached. the subpanel in the shed is being powered by a 40amp double pole from the main service with THHN/THWN 8 gauge wire.

I am going to attach PVC conduit along side of the house (about 30 feet) to bypass some digging because some cables are in the way in the ground.

when I am at the end of the house, thats when I will go into the ground and bring it back up in the shed.

so I am just trying to figure out if I am allowed to run conduit along my house to power up my shed or am I only allowed up to a certain feet?

Like, if im allowed to go straight conduit attached to the house to feed the shed vs burying it, am I alloweD?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's permitted in Article 225. But...

If exposed to temperature extremes, you must provide "expansion fittings" per 300.7 and as a general rule, running it along the side of a building wall usually qualifies as exposure to temperature extremes.

Article 352 ALL pertains to using PVC conduit, but there are a couple of things to note:
A) 352.12 says that you can't use it where subject to physical damage, but...
B) 352.10 had just said that you CAN use it. The subtle and often missed detail is that 352.10 has a note explaining that ***SCHEDULE 80*** PVC ***is*** allowed for use where physical damage is probable. If you are unsure of how your situation applies, just use Schedule 80.

Comment: Wouldn't EMT also work for this application (and potentially cost less than Sch. 80)?

Comment: @HariGanti - You could use EMT but only for the portion above the ground and since it's outside, you would have to use WT or compression connectors and couplings. Then transition to PVC for the underground. Also beware of the "no more than 360% of bends before adding a pull section of some sort."